# How to write regular expression to get the substring from the string using regular expression in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have following string

```
string s=@"\Users\Public\Roaming\Intel\Wireless\Settings";
```

I want output string like

```
string output="Wireless";
```

Sub-string what I want should be after **"Intel\"** and it should ends with the first **"\"** after  **"Intel\"** before string `Intel`  and after `Intel`  the string may be different.
I have achieved it using string.substring() but I want to get it using regular expression ? what regular expression should I write to get that string.

Comment: `split` by `\` and get `4`th element

Comment: I need to use regular expression only. I don't want to split the string and convert it to string array. and the position of the string is not always 4 it may be anything.

Comment: @manish a regular expression would do the same thing on lower level

Comment: @Xyv what does lower level means in this case ?

Comment: Oh wait I think I get what you mean now, is this what you're looking for? `/(intel\\)(\w+\\?)+/gi`

Comment: you don't need a regex to solve your requirement. `input.Split('\\').SkipWhile(s => s != "Intel").Skip(1).First();` should do just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex, it will look like

```
var txt = @"\Users\Public\Roaming\Intel\Wireless\Settings";
var res = Regex.Match(txt, @"Intel\\([^\\]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

But usually, you should use string methods with such requirements. Here is a demo code (without error checking):

```
var strt = txt.IndexOf("Intel\\") + 6;   // 6 is the length of "Intel\"
var end = txt.IndexOf("\\", strt + 1);   // Look for the next "\"
var res2 = txt.Substring(strt, end - strt); // Get the substring
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/HETEmB)

Comment: Just a note on error checking with a non-regex approach: check if the indices are more than -1: `if (strt > -1) {...}`...

Answer (score 3):

For a regex solution you may use:

```
(?<=intel\\)([^\\]+?)[\\$]
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/eBUXLWbWJk)

Notice the `i` flag.

BTW, Split is much simpler and faster solution than regexes. Regex is associated with *patterns* of string. For a static/fixed string structure, it is a wise solution to manipulate it with string functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this if you want everything AFTER the *intel/*

```
/(?:intel\\)((\w+\\?)+)/gi
```

http://regexr.com/3blqm

You would need the `$1`outcome. Note that $1 will be empty or none existent if the string does not contain Intel/ or anything after it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
string s = @"\Users\Public\Roaming\Intel\Wireless\Settings";
string output = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(s));
Debug.Assert(output == "Wireless");
```

It is possible to iterate over directory components until you find the word `Intel` and return the next component.